# MongoDb lte/ lt query behaving unexpectedly

Tags: mongodb

I have connected to mongoDb using Spring. While creating query using Criteria, lt/ lte are not behaving the way they should i.e they are giving random outputs.

I want to Find a store within "x" miles of a zipcode

Query Creation/ execution code:

```
System.out.println("Please Enter your zipCode");
            String zipCode = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the distance (miles) to find store");
            Integer distance = br.read();

            Query query = new Query();
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("storeDistance").lt(distance).and("storezipCode").is(zipCode));

            List<Store>storeList = mongoOperation.find(query, Store.class);

            if(storeList.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("Oops...no store found nearby...!!");
            }else{
                for(int idx=0; idx<storeList.size(); idx++){
                    System.out.println(storeList.get(idx).storeIdentificationumber+"\t"+storeList.get(idx).storeDistance);
                }
            }
```

Store model class

```
package com.storeApp.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection= "stores")
public class Store {

    @Id
    public String storeIdentificationumber;

    public String storeName;
    public String storezipCode;
    public String storeCity;
    public Integer storeDistance;

    public Store(){}

    public Store(String id, String name, String city, String zipCode, Integer distance){
        this.storeIdentificationumber = id;
        this.storeName = name;
        this.storezipCode = zipCode;
        this.storeCity = city;
        this.storeDistance = distance;
    }
}
```

Entries in Database :

```
{
        "_id" : "store1",
        "storeName" : "store One",
        "storezipCode" : "123",
        "storeCity" : "city",
        "storeDistance" : 51
}
{
        "_id" : "store03",
        "storeName" : "Store Three",
        "storezipCode" : "123",
        "storeCity" : "city",
        "storeDistance" : 54
}
```

Input :

```
Welcome to Store Application....!!
Please select choice from menu below
1. Add a Store
2. Find a Store
3. Remove a Store
2
Please Enter your zipCode
123
Enter the distance (miles) to find store
50
```

Expected Output :

```
Oops...no store found nearby...!!
```

Actual Output :

```
store1  51
```

According to the criteria and database, there should be no store whose distance is less than 50 miles, but still one record is being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with `Integer distance = br.read();` Assuming br is instance of BufferedReader. `read` method just reads a single character and gives the integer value of that character. You can verify by printing the `distance` variable.

You need to use `readLine` and convert the String number using `Integer.parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah It's little weird, thing is if you want to add multiple options in your query, you should keep adding Criteria, One Criteria cannot take multiple fields.

In your case storezipCode is removing  storeDistance from the Criteria chief field.

Try this

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("storeDistance").lt(distance));
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("storezipCode").is(zipCode));
```

So question is in what scenario you would use 'and', You need to lookout for examples but it doesn't work the way we want it to work.